# Paraview glyph uniform distribution does not work on my dataset

Tags: python, paraview

I'm running Paraview 4.2 on Linux. Here's what's happening:

1. I load my XDMF/hdf5 data into PV, which contains vector data.
2. I apply a glyph filter to the loaded data, and hit apply (thereby using the default mode of Uniform Spatial Distribution).
3. No glyphs appear on screen, and the information tab shows that the filter has no data (0 points, etc.).
4. If I switch to All Points, or Every Nth Point, it works fine and displays the glyphs oriented correctly.

Annoyingly, if I then make a cone source, and change the input of the glyph to the cone, Uniform Spatial Distribution works fine for the cone.

No errors come up anywhere when I do this, whether in the PV GUI or through `pvpython`.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Utkarsh [Here is some sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qpwoe76kndlojf5/sampledata.tar.gz?dl=0). To open the data in Paraview, use the XDMF.Fields.00999.xmf file.


I did as you asked, and ran a script to test the impact of the seed. From 0 to 20,000, varying the seed does impact the result - but I only ever manage to get 3 arrows at most. The script and results are in the sampledata.tar.gz file.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have a data set with a few hundred points. When I use a Glyph filter to display arrows for Normals, in "Uniform Spatial Distribution" mode I have to set Maximum Number of Sample Points to 27 before I see only 2 arrows.  This is Paraview 5.2.0-RC1.

Answer (score 0):

Uniform distribution works by picking a set of random locations in space and finding data points closet to those locations to glyph. Try playing with the **Seed** to see if that helps pick different random locations that yield better results.

If you could share the data, that'd make it easier to figure out what could be going on here, as well.

Comment: I have uploaded some sample data.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this so late - but a new thing! If you change the "maximum number of sample points" to be something very high (>1e6), it will display more arrows - but it takes forever to compute.